# How can I install .ipa file to my iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode-simulator

I need to install .ipa file to my iPhone simulator.

I tried to change the extension .ipa to .zip and extracted it.

And I got the Payload folder and moved the application inside to my iPhone simulators applications folder found at: `/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/`.

Application appears on iPhone Simulator, But the application did't running.
How to solve the problem then how to run the app.

Comment: Related: [Difference between iPhone Simulator and Android Emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4544588/55075)

Answer (score 9):

#### You can't.

IPAs downloaded from the App Store are built for the ARM processor in actual iOS devices. The iPhone Simulator is not an emulator and can't run ARM code.